# Is Sodium Laurate (SL) the same as Sodium Lauryl Sulfate (SLS) and Sodium Laureth Sulfate (SLES)?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, soap

Is Sodium Laurate (SL) the same as Sodium Lauryl Sulfate (SLS) and Sodium Laureth Sulfate (SLES)?

There's controversy surrounding using SLS and SLES ingredients due to possible carcinogens. However, some soaps doesn't have SLS or SLES but has SL. Does SL have the same controversy surrounding it as SLS and SLES have? Is SL a skin irritant?

Comment: Short answer: no. SL, SLS and SLES are three different compounds. You can find their structures quite easily on Wikipedia and other general information sites.

Comment: Though health is not a topic https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4651417/#:~:text=There%20is%20no%20scientific%20evidence%20supporting%20that%20SLS%20is%20a%20carcinogen.&text=SLS%20is%20not%20listed%20as,Agency%3B%20and%20the%20European%20Union. and stuff like that...

Answer (score 7):

No they are not the same thing.

[Sodium laurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_laurate) is the sodium salt of lauric acid $\ce{CH3(CH2)10CO2Na}.$

[Sodium lauryl sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_dodecyl_sulfate) is the same compound as sodium dodecyl sulfate (SDS) and is the sodium salt of a sulfonic acid $\ce{CH3(CH2)11SO4Na}.$

[Sodium laureth sulfate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_laureth_sulfate) is a sodium salt of a sulfonate ester. There may be multiple ether linkages in the long chain giving several variants e.g. laureth-2 sulfate. The generic structure is $\ce{CH3(CH2)11(OCH2CH2)_nOSO3Na}.$